# Is it possible to declare a type exported from module as global?

Tags: typescript, redux

Let's say I have a type exported from regular module:

```js
const reducer = combineReducers({
  project: projectReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;
```

The exported type `RootState` relies on `reducer` function, so I don't need to write additional code if more reducers added.

I also have a `index.d.ts` file contains types and interfaces declared for global scope. As far as I know, I can not use `import` statements inside ambient declarations file, otherwise it becomes a module file, which should be imported in order to get access to types declared inside.

So is there any way to declare a locally exported type (`RootState` in current case) in global scope?